# Move users from SFB on-perm to Teams\SFBO

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, skype-for-business

Updated SFB-prem to CU9 but for some reason unable to move test user to Teams or SFBO. anyone facing this issue?

I tried to used PS commands and SFB admin portal but same results

```
$cred=Get-Credential
$url="https://admxxxx.online.lync.com/HostedMigration/hostedmigrationService.svc" 

Move-CsUser -Identity teamstestuser02@xxx.com -Target sipfed.online.lync.com -Credential $cred -HostedMigrationOverrideUrl $url
```

> Move-CsUser : Unable to connect to some of the servers in pool
>   "XXX.com" due to a Distributed Component Object Model (DCOM) error.
>   Verify that Front End service is running on servers in this pool. If
>   the pool is set up for load balancing, verify that load balancer is
>   configured  correctly. At line:2 char:1
>   + Move-CsUser -Identity teamstestuser02@XXXX.com -Target "sip ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (CN=TeamsTestUse...p,xx.xxcom:OCSADUser) [Move-CsUser],
>   MoveUserException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveError,Microsoft.Rtc.Management.AD.Cmdlets.MoveOcsUserCmdlet

Comment: I used Force parameter and the user was moved successfully but this is not a solution because force deletes all contacts of that user!! I am still don't know the root cause but will update if figure it out!!

Comment: Please create a support ticket on this from the admin centre.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run this on the FrontEnd Server itself?
I have hit and misses with Move-CsUser when it targets SkypeOnline

Potential mitigations I found:

-Run on FE

-Specify undocumented Switch -DomainController to point it at a writable DC

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/skypeforbusiness/hybrid/move-users-between-on-premises-and-cloud should have all the juice you need, make sure that the user you are running this command as (i.E. logged into the FE) has CsServerAdministrator and the $Cred has Global Admin or User Admin + Skype For Business Admin

Hope that helps :)

Comment: tried to use -UseOAuth but still getting the same SQL error even from the front end server.                       Move-CsUser: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow 
remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
At line:3 char:1

Comment: The Oauth Switch is for CU8 and up to change how you communicate with Office 365. While this should be OK here, you have a different issue: You cannot connect to the SQL Server.
This happens if you are not running the command on the FE Server hosting the User. Move-CsUser is fickle and if you do not align the stars for them, it won't work.
so: Run on FE hosting the User, run with Oauth and specify a DC.
Additionally - and for testing purposes - I would also try dropping the firewall on the SQL Server (temporarily!)(this was one issue we found for other pool-related issues)
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I used -UseOAuth switch on the Frond End server and the issue resolved. Some users return errors for Rollback, and nothing works for these users until I used force switch, which they lost their contacts and meeting info.